# Is it possible to mask tethering usage from my Android service provider (Team Mobile) in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, android, tethering

Under the Windows OS, I was able to tether via USB from my droid without being detected by my carrier.  This was thanks to the special features of PdaNet which allow you to mask your tether usage and avoid data limits applied by carriers to tether users.

For that to be able to work, it requires the installation of a piece of companion software on the PC side which is not Linux compatible.  I would be grateful to anyone who knows if there is some way, perhaps by means of a virtual windows environment, that I could manage to install and run that other .exe in Linux.  The difficulty is that if the app is sand-boxed inside the virtual app I may not be able to access the Internet signal in Ubuntu.

If more specific information is needed to answer this question, please advise.